# update timestamp on parent table if child table gets updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

let's say I've a folio table (id, name, lastModified)

and a child table article (id, name, folio_id, lastModified).

I want to update the parent table's lastModified if child table gets updated. How can I have it done automatically?

p.s. lastModified is a timestamp that gets automatically updated in case of changes.

Comment: how are you planning on updating your child table? there are different ways you could accomplish this but a few i can think of off the top of my head is to put the update into a stored procedure to update both tables or to have a trigger on your child table.

Comment: @rhealitycheck trigger on child table is preferred, please advise

Comment: why don't you try reading the documentation and see if you still have questions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: actually this has more code examples: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @user272195: Note that a trigger on "child" table `article` would not work (and would throw an error) for an `UPDATE` statement that performed an `UPDATE` on rows in `article` if the `UPDATE` statement also referenced "parent" `folio` table.

Comment: @spencer7593 ok, so what'd be the workaround?

Comment: @user272195: If you define an `UPDATE` trigger on `article` that modifies rows in `article`, none of you UPDATE statements can reference the `folio` table (without throwing an error).

Comment: I suggest that you not do this at all.  It makes the field misleading.  You can always select the max timestamp of the children when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would have handled this from within my application code..

however you could use triggers to do this job, simply create a trigger when a update of a record is performed;

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_childupdate]
   ON [dbo].[childtable]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
       ..... code to update parent table..
       WHERE dbo.folio.id = updated.folio_id

END
```

Comment: This SQL Server syntax. The syntax for MySQL is a little different. i.e. use backticks around identifiers (not square braces), include `FOR EACH ROW`, references to modified values of e.g. `folio_id` column would be **`NEW.folio_id`**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent's lastModified to always be the max value of all children's lastModified, I would recommend **NOT EVEN STORING** the value on the parent explicitly and instead get the value by querying the child table dynamically. *Yes, each and every time* The advantages of having accurate and normalized data (and not having performance-killing triggers) outweigh the downside of querying the child table each time (assuming you have Foreign Key for the parent/child, index, etc.).

For example, if you did this, an alternate way of expressing the Parent table would be:

```
create view vFolio as
select id, name, lastModified=(
                     select max(a.lastModified) 
                     from article a where a.folio_id = f.id
                 )
from folio f
```

Comment: What if there are no children?

Comment: If you want the Folio to have a lastModified even if there are no articles, then I would put a createDate on the folio, and then have the dynamically pulled lastModified = isnull(<subquery above>, createDate). Note that in this case the date field on the Folio does does not re-create the original problem - it is a different field with a different meaning that happens to be useful in a similar way.

Comment: what if the parent is also updatable? If you change a column in the  parent row, there is no way to tell if it is updated or not using your method.

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan - then that would change the problem statement, wouldn't it?  Although the OP doesn't even touch on the requirement you mention, you certainly could have a `case` statement that checks the parent's own `lastModifiedDate` and compares it with all of the children's `lastModifiedDate` values and takes the latest value.  As the problem changes, so will the solution...

Comment: This way you have inconsistent behavior. if you execute a select query without join you get a 'lastModifiedDate' which is different than the one you get with join. These values respresents different logic so they should have their own seperate columns like 'selfUptadedAt' and 'childUpdatedAt'.

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan the OP said "I want to update the parent table's lastModified if child table gets updated". You are pointing out valid design considerations, and I don't disagree with you, but IMO this is well beyond the scope of the OP's question.